# How to handle Missking keys and null values for keys coming from dictionary in python

Tags: python

Trying to handle missking keys and null values for keys coming from dictionary in python. Here are all `resources` have `tags`, but some do not. I tried to handle none values as below, but I keep getting errors.

**What I tried is:**

```
tags_info = []
resource_list = client.resources.list()
for item in (resource_list):        
    tags = item.tags
    managed_tag_value = tags['managed']
    if not managed_tag_value:
        tags_info = {"Managed": "Not Managed"}
    else:    
        tags_info = {"Managed": managed_tag_value}
    print(tags_info)
```

**Error:**

```
managed_tag_value = tags['managed']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I handle any none values results in dictionary filled with any other default value like Not Available or so?

**EDIT 1:**

Sample data of how each iteration of my `resources.list()` output `item`as below

```
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/xxxxx', 'name': 'resourcename1', 'type': 'Microsoft.Compute/snapshots', 'location': 'southeastasia', 'tags': {'Name': 'xxxxxx', 'owner': 'xxxxxx', 'created date': '06022020', 'purpose': 'xxxx', 'Retention days ': 'NA'}, 'plan': None, 'properties': None, 'kind': None, 'managed_by': None, 'sku': xxxxxx, 'identity': None, 'created_time': None, 'changed_time': None, 'provisioning_state': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxx', 'name': 'resourcename2', 'type': 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', 'location': 'eastus', 'tags': {'Function': 'Fetch', 'Division': 'PH', 'managed_by': 'xxxxxx',  'managed': 'notbillable'}, 'plan': None, 'properties': None, 'kind': None, 'managed_by': None, 'sku': None, 'identity': None, 'created_time': None, 'changed_time': None, 'provisioning_state': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxx/extensions/MicrosoftMonitoringAgent', 'name': 'BastionRDP/MicrosoftMonitoringAgent', 'type': 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions', 'location': 'eastus', 'tags': None, 'plan': None, 'properties': None, 'kind': None, 'managed_by': None, 'sku': None, 'identity': None, 'created_time': None, 'changed_time': None, 'provisioning_state': None}
```

**The following scenarios I need to address:**

1. I need to find out tags for each dictionary and also while doing so I need to get only `'managed'` key from tags if there are multiple items in `tags`.
2. If `'managed'` key is `null` then, set its value as `'Not Tagged'`
3. If `'tags'` key itself doesnot exist in dictionary above then, it should display `"Tags key missing"`

Comment: Is "tags" sometimes None?  If yes, you can't do tags['managed'].

Comment: yeah, sometimes tags is none for any of resource group so I need to print for those as "not managed"

Comment: managed_tag_value = tags['managed'] if tags else None

Comment: sorry could not get it ..can you properly format it please...

Comment: I don't know what else you want, I wrote the line of code for you.

Comment: let me give a try.. thanks

Comment: Hi its works now if value is is none, i need little improvement that if Key of Managed it self not present then also it should print `None : None ` possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219747/discussion-between-asp-and-user2263572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to check if the key exists before you assign the value.

```
tags_info = []
for item in client.resource_groups.list():
    print(item.name)
    tags = item.tags
    if 'managed' in tags.keys(): #this will prevent the error. assume tags is a dictionary
        managed_tag_value = tags['managed']
        if not managed_tag_value:
            tags_info = {"Managed": "Not Managed"}
        else:    
            tags_info = {"Managed": managed_tag_value}
        print(tags_info)
```

You could even simplify your code further by doing this:

```
tags_info = []
for item in client.resource_groups.list():
    print(item.name)
    tags = item.tags
    if 'managed' in tags.keys(): #this will prevent the error. assume tags is a dictionary
        tags_info = {"Managed": tags['managed']}
    else:    
        tags_info = {"Managed": "Not Managed"}
    print(tags_info)
```

Also, can you please share the contents of client.resource_groups. It looks like a dictionary. It may be easier to simplify this further.

Assuming resource_groups is a dictionary and key has `'Managed'`. as a value, you can do the following.

Let's assume resource_groups is a dictionary with the following data items:

```
resource_groups = {
    'abcd':'sample data 1',
    'defg':'sample data 2',
    'pqrs':'sample data 3', 
    'wxyz':'sample data 4'}
```

Then you can directly check if key `'wxyz'` exists and if it does, you can do something about it. The code would look like this.

```
tag_info = {}
if 'wxyz' in resource_groups.keys():
    tags_info = {'Managed':resource_groups['wxyz']}
else:
    tags_info = {'Managed':'Not Managed'}
print(tags_info)
```

**NEW ANSWER BASED ON SAMPLE DATA**

```
r = {
 '1':{'additional_properties': {},
 'id': '/subscriptions/1111xxxxx/rest of text',
 'name': 'sxxxxxxx',
 'type': 'Microsoft.Compute/snapshots',
 'location': 'southeastasia',
 'tags': {
     'Name': '1111name',
     'owner': 'xxxxxx',
     'created date': '06022020',
     'purpose': 'xxxx',
     'Retention days ': 'NA'},
 'plan': None,
 'properties': None,
 'kind': None,
 'managed_by': None,
 'sku': 'xxxxxx',
 'identity': None,
 'created_time': None,
 'changed_time': None,
 'provisioning_state': None},

 '2':{'additional_properties': {},
 'id': '/subscriptions/2222xxxxxxx/rest of text',
 'name': '2222name',
 'type': 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines',
 'location': 'eastus',
 'tags': {
     'Function': 'Fetch',
     'Division': 'PH',
     'managed_by': '222xxx',
     'managed': 'notbillable'},
 'plan': None,
 'properties': None,
 'kind': None,
 'managed_by': None,
 'sku': None,
 'identity': None,
 'created_time': None,
 'changed_time': None,
 'provisioning_state': None},

 '3':{'additional_properties': {},
 'id': '/subscriptions/3333xxxx/remaining text',
 'name': 'BastionRDP/MicrosoftMonitoringAgent',
 'type': 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions',
 'location': 'eastus',
 'tags': None,
 'plan': None,
 'properties': None,
 'kind': None,
 'managed_by': None,
 'sku': None,
 'identity': None,
 'created_time': None,
 'changed_time': None,
 'provisioning_state': None}
}

tags_info = {}

for k,v in r.items():
    #first check if name is a key
    if 'name' in v.keys():
        #then store name as a value
        tags_info['name'] = v['name']
    else:
        #store 'No Name' as a value
        tags_info['name'] = 'No Name'
    #check if 'tags' is a key and
    #check if 'tags' is a dictionary
    if 'tags' in v.keys() and v['tags']:
        #check if 'managed' is a key inside 'tags' dictionary
        if 'managed' in v['tags'].keys():
            #then we got what we want
            tags_info['Managed'] = v['tags']['managed']
        else:
            #tags does not have 'managed' as a key
            tags_info['Managed'] = 'Not Managed'
        print (tags_info)
    else:
        #tags is not a dictionary so it is not managed
        tags_info['Managed'] = 'Not Managed'
        print (tags_info)
```

**Output for the above code is:**

```
{'name': '1111name', 'Managed': 'Not Managed'}
{'name': '2222name', 'Managed': 'notbillable'}
{'name': 'BastionRDP/MicrosoftMonitoringAgent', 'Managed': 'Not Managed'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help !... Let me try this way. Yeah resource_groups are dictionary values...

Comment: can you give me example of contents resource_group. I think you may not need tags and many other items.

Comment: Yeah updating with sample data and clearer requirement shortly

Comment: I made up some sample data to show you how we can implement the simplified code. see if this helps you.

Comment: Hi @Joe Ferndz sorry for delay, just updated post now under EDIT 1 section sample data i have and some problems i need to address.. can you check. Please let me know if you need further inputs to help me :).. thank you again

Comment: small update it should be `client.resource_groups.list():` to be replaced by `client.resources.list()` . This is to get right resources than group(changed due to functional requirment). Updated my original code as well reflecting this.. FYI

Comment: see my new answer. It is a lengthy one.

Comment: did you update the answer,, not able to see your update...if yet to post, then i shall wait :)

Comment: check again. let me know if you want me to print the response for 3rd item as well

Comment: Yes, please, for third item too. would like to add `name` also to output as well, ie `name` key

Comment: Ok. added code to cover for the third one as well. See if this is helpful. If so, up vote my response and flag code as answered. Happy to expand on this. It was fun writing the code for this.

Comment: haha. thank you very much buddy for your patience :) thanks a lot, would like to  add `name` of the resource for each item...possible? actually the dictionary i get from via api which is very nesty and complex..hmm. Thanks for help again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219855/discussion-between-asp-and-joe-ferndz).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: `tags["managed"]` will never work if tags is none. It's like typing `9.5[0]`. You simply can't index it because it does not have indexes.
Secondly, if you want to print something if they type none, DON'T edit your code and try this:

```
try:
   [insert code here]
except TypeError as error:
    print("Not subscriptable")
```

When it throws an error, the except statement catches it, but only if it throws a TypeError. This means that if you put 9.5 instead of None, the output would be the same.